# I have extended my Django model from AbstractUser, how do I query the extended model to get date_joined of the user?

Tags: python, django

I have created a model class which extends from **AbstractUser** to handle token authentication, how do I get **date_joined** property of the modal's object when querying it in django rest framework views.py?

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from .managers import CustomUserManager




# Create your models here.


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Here is my Managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password,**extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

This my drf view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def report2(request):
    user_data = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    print("User data ",user_data)
    return Response("date_joined", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The user_data only returns email_id, I expect it to return all the attributes of the table including date_joined.

Below is an image from my database:
[image]

Kindly someone guide me, how can I get **date_joined** attribute of the CustomUser object in my view function?

Thanks

Comment: `user_data.date_joined`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, it worked, thanks, my bad.